# How to get nil values also from where query in POSTGRES in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I am trying to get all rows which are not a column is not a particular value.

```
Task.where('owner_user_id != ?', 429)
```

However this does not return rows which have the owner_user_id to be nil. I want to try is distinct from, but am getting the following error.

```
Task.where('owner_user_id is distinct from (429)')
  Task Load (2.3ms)  SELECT  "tasks".* FROM "tasks" WHERE (owner_user_id is distinct from (429)) LIMIT 10 OFFSET 0
  SQLite3::SQLException: near "distinct": syntax error: SELECT  "tasks".* FROM "tasks" WHERE (owner_user_id is distinct from (429)) LIMIT 10 OFFSET 0
  #<Task::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x007f07940ea338>
```

How can I get all the rows where a column is not a particular value (including all the rows which contain nil)?

Comment: You're asking about postgresql, but the error you report is a SQLite3 error -- are you sure you're connecting to the right database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would fire one single query and give you the results including `nil` values:

```
Task.where('owner_user_id != ? OR owner_user_id IS NULL', 429)
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

This will fire 2 queries but this will return the desired result

```
Task.where.not(id: Task.where(owner_user_id: 429).pluck(:id))
```

Answer (score 0):

`!=` is the ruby way of saying "not equal" in postgres/sql, though, you need `<>` instead, so

```
Task.where('owner_user_id <> ?', 429)
```

or in arel you can also do:

```
Task.where.not(:owner_user_id => 429)
```

Comment: <> and != is the same things. https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-comparison.html

Comment: Yes. This answer is based on a mis-reading of mine. The answer is wrong.